# What operator works for equal in td .ms-vb2?

Tags: javascript

I have used td .ms-vb2:contains but I need to match an exact value in a cell.

Comment: You'll probably have to do some sort of for each loop, without any code to go off of and what the page output looks like, it'll be hardpressed to give you an exact answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery filter function to provide an exact match - http://api.jquery.com/filter/

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("td .ms-vb2").filter( function (index) {

       return $(this).text() == "Exact value to be matched";

    })
    .css("background-color", "red");

});
```

See this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883922/jquery-text-match